# Pivot dates as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have something like this:

[image]

From this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Securitization, SUM(RemittableCollections) [RemittableCollections], ReportingDate
FROM Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting
GROUP BY Securitization,ReportingDate
```

What I want is the Reporting dates to be on the rows, so I will have securitzation as the columns and then for each reporting date I will have a sum of Remittable collections, how can I do this?

This is what I am trying to do but it doesnt work

```
SELECT DISTINCT Securitization, ReportingDate
FROM Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting
PIVOT
(
 SUM(RemittableCollections)
 for dates in (SELECT DISTINCT ReportingDate FROM Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting )
)
GROUP BY Securitization,ReportingDate
```

Comment: It would a nice feature to "SELECT DISTINCT ..." for the columns to pivot.  However, you can only do this with Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but perhaps this will help

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (Select Distinct 
               Securitization
              ,ReportingDate
              ,RemittableCollections
         From  Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting 
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(RemittableCollections) for ReportingDate in ( ' + Stuff((Select Distinct 
                                                                             ',' + QuoteName(ReportingDate) 
                                                                       From  Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting 
                                                                       Order By 1 
                                                                       For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  +' ) ) pvt
'
--Print(@SQL)
Exec(@SQL)
```

---

**EDIT - Remove NULLS**

```
Declare @NoNulls varchar(max) = Stuff( (
Select Distinct 
       ',' + QuoteName(ReportingDate) +' = IsNull(' + QuoteName(ReportingDate) +',0)'
 From  Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting  
 Order By 1 
 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select [Securitization]
      ,' + @NoNulls + '
 From  (Select Distinct 
               Securitization
              ,ReportingDate
              ,RemittableCollections
         From  Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting 
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(RemittableCollections) for ReportingDate in ( ' + Stuff((Select Distinct 
                                                                             ',' + QuoteName(ReportingDate) 
                                                                       From  Securitization.dbo.SecuritizationReporting 
                                                                       Order By 1 
                                                                       For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  +' ) ) pvt
'
--Print(@SQL)
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Any how to remove the NULLS ?

Comment: @Wolfy Yes there are two ways.  One (the easiest and perhaps less performant) is to do a UNION ALL of possible combinations.   If your data is big, I would suggest NOT doing this.  The second is to create two strings of columns,  one as is, and the second with ISNull().   Give me a minute

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It has zeros now anyway of making them just blank?

Comment: If not no worries

Comment: @Wolfy  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d68e38f7ae1865a78d4738c2169067ae

Comment: @Wolfy Here is one option that will still use SUM().  We just use concat() rather than is null  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d5216286d1d335bfccbdd36139addd86

Comment: Nice on John!!  Very nice!!